# Как хранить корзину на сайте?

Tags: java, cart

Здравствуйте, назрел вопрос. Как вы думайте, как лучше всего реализовать корзину интернет магазина. Кто то считает, что нужно её хранить в БД, но (!) как писал Кристофер Дейт (известный человек, лучший специалист баз данных). Что в базе желательно хранить, перманентные данные, а корзина эта именно тут объект, который уж больно динамический.

Хранение в сессии самый легкий вариант, но еще предлагаю хранить в куки. Кто то предположит, что если человек зайдет с другого браузера на сайт, то у него буду разные корзины, но вы часто встречали таких людей, которые так делают ?

И все же, хотелось получить более развернутый ответ, каким путем реализовать корзину. Интересует ответ с уклоном на язык Java (можно и другой ООП, только не какой не PHP или js)

Comment: Вы неправильно понимаете «перманентные» данные. Перечитайте ещё раз этого самого Кристофера Дейта: под то определение «перманентным данным», которые даёт он в своей книжке, корзина прекрасно подходит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из корзины заказ будет отправляться куда? Кто-то будет обрабатывать заказ, собирать заказанное, доставлять, оставлять отзыв? Вы будете смотреть движение и наличие товаров, собирать статистику по заказам?

Теперь представьте, что заказ существует только в тот мимолётный момент, когда пользователь отправляет форму заказа вам. В этот момент вы должны будете сразу сделать всё, что вы должны сделать с заказом, потому что в следующий момент времени — после обработки запроса — данные перестанут существовать, пользователь закроет браузер.

Если вы сможете так сделать, то печенья или локального хранилища на клиенте хватит. В противном случае — БД.

Comment: Я понял. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Зависит от того, что будет лежать в корзине. Если это большой интернет магазин с функциональностью aliexpress, то корзина должна сохраняться в течении месяцев и её нужно хранить в БД.

Если это небольшой магазин, как продажа видеоигр, где пользователи если и набирают корзину, то покупают всё сразу - корзину можно хранить в сессиях или куки.